# Android Studio not fetching documentation properly

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio editor, the ctrl-q and/or code completion popup to show related documentation does not give documentation on object. I only get a window claiming that URL's have been searched.

the following is the text from a typical popup: (with my notes in parentheses)

```
java.io.File public String toString()
 Overrides:

toString in class Object
The following documentation urls were checked:  
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#toString--
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#toString()

       Edit API docs paths (<-- acts like link, does nothing)

`toString()` on developer.android.com (<-- is link, goes to ../File)
`toString()` on developer.android.com (<-- is link, goes to ../File.html#toString())
```

What am I missing? Can I fix this? Setup is api 29

Comment: Have you installed all appliciable Android SDks?

Comment: I was kind of under the impression that because I had been building and running my application that the SDks were there.  It seams to be looking up api 29 which is installed.  I was also under the impression that it was going to the web to find the information so I am not sure how the downloaded SDks make a difference.

Comment: could I maybe have the android studio to be looking for local files?

Comment: Are you able to manually navigate to the page that is being requested?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant with the (<-- this goes to) statements, I guess that was unclear. I had trouble formatting the layout the way I wanted it and lost my first draft. not used to the way the editor works yet. I thought I had said I can paste them into the browser and get there.

Comment: I can actually click on the links in the popup too.  I'm just not used to the dearth of information in this window and I am seeing it a lot using api 29

Comment: It does it on apis 29 28 27 even if I have the sdk down loaded. do I need to download documentation? (changed target in .gradle file) Seems like before I had to clear my system and reistall, heck, even last week it was better than just, basically, repeating the completion popup.

Comment: I'm using AS 3.5 built aug. 8 , 2019.  I went back to older example Droid Café using api 26 and the help that pops up looks the same. like I say, I remember it being more descriptive.

Comment: Seems to be a common problem with new versions of Android Studio.  What's the point of "instant" documentation if we have to go to a web page anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the specific sdk versions used by my project (like suggested by Ramhound in the comments) fixed the problem for me.

(Through Tools -> SDK Manager)

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative solution to downloading SDK via manager

1. Create any data structure that doesn't fetch documentation  e.g. a *HashMap* `Map<String, String> testMap = new  HashMap<>();`
2. add any random thing to the *Hashmap*: `testMap.put("test", "test");`
3. Put your cursor on the `put()` method that you just call above, go to definition by holding `ctrl + b` or `cmd+b` for mac users.
4. **De-compile the byte code** and just click `decide later`.
5. When it opens up, you should see at the top ~

   - *"Cannot find source for Android API: xx(depending on what version your compile sdk is set to in build.gradle(app))"*
6. Click an option to `Download` the source (or refresh)
7. After download finishes let indexes **refresh**!

Documentation should now work within the IDE.

*Credits to the [amani-arman on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839972/19328232)*